# Find GET Attribute in jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, php-curl

I getting data from a Webpage and it have a jQuery Ajax Request. its Method is GET and it have some data, i wanna know how i can send request with cURL-php.

i did run a curl session and send data with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas)`
but it didn't respond.

```
// $.ajax({type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', url : 'http://example.com/some', data: $('#media_form').serialize()})
// $('#media_form').serialize() = string=string&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

actually i put #media_form data in an array into postfields in cURL, but in fact i even dont know how should i send request. **how should i send data in GET without any Attribute ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` parameters are put in the URL, not the `POST` fields.

So it should be:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/some?string=string&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com';
```

You can use the `http_build_str()` function to construct the query string from an associative array of parameters.